# Printf char[] buffer overflow

Tags: c, printf

I've this problem, my nome's is a char[20], if I insert some character the array comes into overflow and write in the other array (cognome).

I've tried to change the scanf() with puts(), but this last one wont work properly because it jump off the input and doesn't read nothing.

---

Someone know solutions?

Here is the code

```
void addStudent(){
    struct student s;
    printf("Inserire Nome: ");
    scanf("%20s",s.nome);
    printf("\nInserire Cognome: ");
    scanf("%30s",s.cognome);
    printf("\nInserire eta': ");
    scanf("%d",&s.anni);
}
```

Result

```
Inserire Nome: cjhsdjkhbsdkhfgsdjkhfgskjhgjkhsfs

Inserire Cognome: 
Inserire eta':
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change to `"%19s"`. It must be one less than the array size as `scanf()` writes a null terminator. After the calls to `scanf()` you need to skip any unprocessed input, which can be achieved by reading until the next new-line character:

```
int ch;
while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF && ch != '\n');
```

Comment: <code>
printf("Inserire Nome: ");
    scanf("%19s",s.nome);
    printf("\nInserire Cognome: ");
    scanf("%29s",s.cognome); <\code>
Same Problem:
'
Inserire Nome: gauysdgjhasdgjhkasgdjhagdjhgad

Inserire Cognome: 
Inserire eta': 
'

Comment: Can you give me an example with this? @hmjd

`struct student s;
    printf("Inserire Nome: ");
    scanf("%19s",s.nome);
`

Comment: @PsyKoWebMari, after the `scanf()` you need to skip the remaining characaters on the line. You can use the example loop I posted in this answer. If you don't skip it, it will be processed by the next `scanf()`.

Comment: Ok Thank you, I've understand now. Great Work!

Answer (score 0):

you're off by one character, you should leave one character for the null byte, same applies to `s.cognome`

```
scanf("%19s",s.nome);
```

Also, `scanf` and `puts` are not interchangable, the first one reads something, the second outputs something, you probably mean `gets` or better `fgets`:

```
fgets(s.nome, 20, stdin);
```

Comment: I dont know why but if I use fgets the program jump the input and go to the next instruction. @mux

Comment: @PsyKoWebMari `fegts` is not `puts` try it and see if it works.

Comment: It jump...

`printf("Inserire Nome: ");
 fgets(s.nome, 19, stdin);`

`Inserire Nome: 
Inserire Cognome:`